# How can I use a multiple character delimiter when exporting CSV data?

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, delimiter

I have large set of tables that I am exporting from one server. There are particular description attributes that store a boat load of special characters that are clashing with my delimiter specified on the code. I've tried delimiting by pipes, commas, semi colons, brackets, curly brackets, arithmetic signs, even the curly sign next to the 1, and they're all being used in the data. I thought maybe the best way is to delimit by a combined delimiter such as {] or {!] something that won't be used in the data. My issue is powershell export-csv only allow char(1) delimiters, how do you force it to take multiple?

This is what I have:

```
export-csv $raw_file_path -delimiter "{"
```

I want to do this:

```
export-csv $raw_file_path -delimiter "{]"
```

Comment: That's not supported. As [documented](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx) the parameter `-Delimiter` takes a single character.

Comment: This is why CSV will have quoted string data as to prevent this sort of issue. Your data has nested quotes then as well? Do you have some sample data we can see. Does the export need to be CSV? There are other export methods like `Export-CLIXML` that might help here.

Comment: char in PS is a [unicode 16-bit char](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), so there should be any character that's not used in your data.

Comment: Hi, So below is an example of the field thats giving me the issue, it looks like gibberish but believe me is actually needed. Im delimitng by "{ " 

1:2{2{605731{SEQUENCER{3.000{
2g:2{5{753621{M175/U/MED{5.000{
6a:7{0{0{%28-9742   ""||;#   RIGHT ANGLE           {{
3a:8{4{0{%87-7624  "*@$"          {{
1a:2{5{814678{LF 3/8ODx1/2Fx20L SS LAV.SUPPLY{2.000{
1s:1{7{738626{^^X 2000~ ROLL {1.000{
2b:2{8{0{% TWO RAIL{{
5v:3{9{0{%ENVELOPE{{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,in my previous powershell code, I stripped the text qualifiers "", but I actually need them in order for the code to work with a single delimiter.

This is what I was doing:

```
$table = $set.tables[0] | export-csv $raw_file_path -delimiter "{"

#clean "" out of file
(Get-Content $raw_file_path)|%{$_ -replace '"',""}|Out-File FilePath $file_path -Force -Encoding ascii
```

This is what I should of been doing:

```
$table = $set.tables[0] | export-csv $raw_file_path -delimiter "{"

#clean "" out of file
(Get-Content $raw_file_path)|Out-File FilePath $file_path -Force -Encoding ascii
```

Once the import the csv in SQL, I can set a function the can pull the data based on the text qualifier and delimiter. Since the data is wrapped around the text qualifier, it doen't pull the special characters within my data string.